# C# nested lists entry issue

Tags: c#, arrays, nested-lists

I'd like to use nested lists in my data acquistion application to store my incoming 16bit data dynamically. I created a list of UInt16 and added it three times (NUMCHANNEL=3) to a List type list. Now I expect that I can add an Uint16 entry the way the code shows below:

```
public List<UInt16> TBATT16 = new List<UInt16>();
public List<List<UInt16>> LBATT16 = new List<List<UInt16>>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMCHANNEL; ++i)
        {
            LBATT16.Add(TBATT16);
        }

LBATT16[0].Add((ushort)(0x1155));
```

It do add an entry but not only to the LBATT16[0] but to all LBATT16 lists. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your list creation inside the loop:

```
public List<List<UInt16>> LBATT16 = new List<List<UInt16>>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMCHANNEL; ++i)
{
    //Make a unique list for each element
    public List<UInt16> TBATT16 = new List<UInt16>();
    LBATT16.Add(TBATT16);
}

LBATT16[0].Add((ushort)(0x1155));
```

Comment: Thank you, Reed! That's what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have only one `TBATT16` - this is a reference type, meaning that in your `for` loop you're not actually adding new empty list each time, you're just adding the same list over and over again. And then it doesn't matter which reference do you pick - you get the same inner list all the time.

Replace `TBATT16` in your loop body with `new List<UInt16>()` and it'll work as you expect.

For more info on references in C#, see for example [this article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Comment: Thank you A! I was not aware that lists are reference types. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

List is a reference type - so you have the same object 3 times in the LBATT16 list.